# caluclate duration time without date in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe with a column (t1) giving the time someone usually goes to bed and a column (t2) giving the time someone usually gets up, looking like that:

```
ID       t1           t2
p001   22:30:00    7:00:00
...
p055   01:20:00    9:00:00
...
```

I want to create a new column giving the hours spent in bed, computed by those two times. A simple subtraction, like that

```
Df['hoursinbed'] = Df['t2']- Df['t1']
```

of course does not work since the starting time is usually on the day before.

I've also tried this:

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime(Df['t1'])
t2 = pd.to_datetime(Df['t2'])

print (pd.Timedelta(t2-t1).seconds / 60.0)
```

But probably this works only if the start- and end-time includes a date?

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? TIA :)

Comment: convert all times in your dataframe to include a date like (2020-01-01), then if time `t2 < t1` set date of `t2` to (2020-01-02), then subtract the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, add one day to `t2` if `t1 > 12 hours` and then find the difference:

```
df['t1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t1'])
df['t2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t2'])

df['t2'] = np.where(df['t1'].dt.hour > 12, df['t2'] + pd.DateOffset(1), df['t2'])
df['timeinbed'] = df['t2'] - df['t1']

df['t1'] = df['t1'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df['t2'] = df['t2'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')

print(df)

     ID     t1     t2       timeinbed
0  p001  22:30  07:00 0 days 08:30:00
1  p055  01:20  09:00 0 days 07:40:00
```

Comment: unfortunately the first line gives me already this error: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: This needs to be done before you convert your columns to datetime.time

Comment: I didn't convert it, it just comes like this out of excel. Any ideas how I can solve this? Should I first convert the columns into a certain format?

Comment: Convert the columns to string. `df['t1'] = df['t1'].astype(str)`

Comment: thank you, that worked! But I didn't actually specify, in what format I want timeinbed, sorry! I need a decimal number with hh,mm. So, I would either have to drop the days and convert the time or woulrd have compute it differently in the first place?

Comment: You can just do this `df['timeinbed'] = df['timeinbed'].dt.seconds`

Comment: Gives me this error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Comment: Did you add that piece of code after this line: `df['timeinbed'] = df['t2'] - df['t1']`. It cannot give the series error after this line

Comment: Alright, so it doesn't give me that error anymore but the numbers are off like 32400 instead of 9 hours

Comment: Use hours instead of seconds or don't use anything at all

Comment: this worked: Df['timeinbed'] = Df['timeinbed'] / pd.offsets.Hour(1)